# VIM: chmod command is not an editor command

Tags: bash, vim

I am trying to set permission for my file to be executed using the vim text editor. I have been using `:chmod +x filename.sh` but the error pops up that says it is not an editor command. I am even trying to set a path for the directory that my bash.exe and other files are, but I get a similar error. What can I do about this?

Comment: Why not just run `chmod` from the shell?

Comment: @KeithThompson It's often preferable to stay inside the editor, in order not to break the rhythm.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To run an external shell command, you need to use `:!`, not `:`.

```
:!chmod +x filename.sh
```

Also, you can use a `%` and it'll expand to the current filename:

```
:!chmod +x %
```

Comment: I tried that but I got the rror: " 'chmod' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: @user3731263 `chmod` is a unix command. You can look at [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/106181/equivalent-of-chmod-to-change-file-permissions-in-windows) for the Windows equivalent.